# IPP QBO UK v3 - Trouble adding Journal Entry with EntityId

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Intuit Partner Platform - API v3 QBO United Kingdom.

I am properly setting the entity to an existing customer but the journal entry won't save. Line 2 I am using the Debtor account and setting the EntityId to a valid customer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<outgoing><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <JournalEntry xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TxnDate>2014-03-05</TxnDate>
    <PrivateNote>Invoice</PrivateNote>
    <DocNumber>102</DocNumber>
    <Adjustment>false</Adjustment>
    <Line>
      <Desc>Credit Sales</Desc>
      <Amount>150</Amount>
      <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
      <JournalEntryLineDetail>
        <PostingType>Credit</PostingType>
        <AccountRef>1</AccountRef>
        <ClassRef></ClassRef>
        <DepartmentRef></DepartmentRef>
        <BillableStatus></BillableStatus>
      </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Desc>Debit Accounts Receivable</Desc>
      <Amount>150.00</Amount>
      <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
      <JournalEntryLineDetail>
        <PostingType>Debit</PostingType>
        <AccountRef>52</AccountRef>
        <ClassRef></ClassRef>
        <DepartmentRef></DepartmentRef>
        <BillableStatus></BillableStatus>
        <EntityRef>
          <EntityRef>21</EntityRef>
          <Type>Customer</Type>
        </EntityRef>
      </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
  </JournalEntry>
</outgoing>
<returns><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-13T09:22:10.585-07:00">
    <Fault type="ValidationFault">
      <Error code="6000" element="">
        <Message>A business validation error has occurred while processing your request</Message>
        <Detail>Business Validation Error: When you use Debtors, you must choose a customer in the Name field.</Detail>
      </Error>
    </Fault>
  </IntuitResponse>
</returns>
```

Comment: Can you try adding the name also in the <EntityRef>21</EntityRef> tag?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would make any difference since I'm not specifying name within elements for account or anything else. If you can confirm that's the work-around then I can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the response XML for this issue. 
( If you're using devkit, then please set the logger in DEBUG mode, to get the raw request and response XMLs)

PFB one working JE response.

```
<JournalEntry domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>6</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2014-03-10T21:10:17-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-10T21:10:17-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <DocNumber>1</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2014-03-11</TxnDate>
    <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
    <Line>
        <Id>0</Id>
        <Description>Debit</Description>
        <Amount>100.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
        <JournalEntryLineDetail>
            <PostingType>Debit</PostingType>
            <Entity>
                <Type>Customer</Type>
                <EntityRef name="Customer123">2</EntityRef>
            </Entity>
            <AccountRef name="Accounts Receivable (A/R)">48</AccountRef>
            <ClassRef name="CLASS-1">3000000000000199718</ClassRef>
        </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Description>Credit</Description>
        <Amount>100.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
        <JournalEntryLineDetail>
            <PostingType>Credit</PostingType>
            <AccountRef name="Sales">1</AccountRef>
        </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Adjustment>false</Adjustment>
</JournalEntry>
```

QBO UI( US company )

[image]
Thanks

Instead of

```
<EntityRef>
    <EntityRef>21</EntityRef>
    <Type>Customer</Type>
</EntityRef>
```

Please try (as you got from the response)

```
<Entity>
    <Type>Customer</Type>
    <EntityRef name="Right Way Cleaners">21</EntityRef>
</Entity>
```

You had used EntityRef twice in the composite tag.

Comment: Not using DevKit. XML response is there. Issue is trying to add transaction line to Debtors account (UK for A/R) and set the EntityId.

Comment: I need to check this by constructing a suitable JE payload. Can you please try this from QBO UI, by setting debator account and mentioning a customer in the Name column and then try to retrieve that using V3 endpoint to see the construct ?

Comment: Already did that. It works fine in UI. Again this is a Harmony QBO UK company file.

Comment: Which version(simpleStart, essential or plus) of QBO account is it ?

Comment: It's the Plus version and it's a 30 day trial subscription

Comment: After manually entering a JournalEntry I used the API explorer to query for it. Return XML:

      <Line>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Description>Debit Accounts Receivable</Description>
        <Amount>150.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
        <JournalEntryLineDetail>
          <PostingType>Debit</PostingType>
          <Entity>
            <Type>Customer</Type>
            <EntityRef name="Right Way Cleaners">21</EntityRef>
          </Entity>
          <AccountRef name="Debtors">52</AccountRef>
        </JournalEntryLineDetail>
      </Line>

Comment: ok.. after removing the Id from the Line, if you paste the same(Line) while creating another JE using V3 API, then also you're getting the same error response ? Because, it seems there is something wrong in your payload. I'm adding the correction in the above post.

Comment: The documentation of this required business rule is absolutely horrendous on the Quickbooks API documentation site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the tag wrong. It should be Entity and I had EntityRef. Got it working. Thanks for your help.